# Redirected URL through .htaccess is being redirected to the different location

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

My .htaccess has the following code :

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]+)$ listings/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^listings/([A-Z]+)/?$ listings_state.php?state=$1  [NC,L]
```

With this rule I am trying to achieve 301 redirect from `spb.com/test_1/XY` to `spb.com/test_1/listings/XY`

However, it is redirecting to `spb.com/path/to/test_1/in_server/test_1/listings/CT`

and I tried changing .htaccess to as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]+)$ /listings/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^listings/([A-Z]+)/?$ listings_state.php?state=$1  [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/([A-Z]+)$ /listings/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^listings/([A-Z]+)/?$ listings_state.php?state=$1  [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/([A-Z]+)$ /listings/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/listings/([A-Z]+)/?$ listings_state.php?state=$1  [NC,L]
```

Nothing seems to work.

Please guide me in this regard. Thank you community :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples only. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]+)/?$ /test_1/listings/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^test_1/listings/([A-Z]+)/?$ listings_state.php?state=$1 [NC,L]
```